# Install Oracle 11.0.12 failure

Tags: ppa, oracle

I have followed [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html), perfectly with no errors, "jdk-11.0.12_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz" copied to "/var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/" however when I run "sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer-local"  I get the output below, and nothing is installed, still the same Ubuntu OpenJKD and when I try to show alternatives it says none.  I am a Ubuntu newbie but everything is straightforward.

```
root@server:~# sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer-local 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java11-installer-local is already the
newest version (11.0.12-1~linuxuprising0). 0 upgraded, 0 newly
installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Following N0rbert last recommendation.  It appeared to install, and set the environment variable but still shows OpenJDK.  I need to set Tomcat to Oracle JDK and without showing up in alternatives I can...can I? (Also how can I get the block quote to respect or set line break/length?)

> (Reading database ... 93229 files and directories currently
> installed.) Preparing to unpack
> .../oracle-java11-set-default-local_11.0.12-1~linuxuprising0_amd64.deb
> ... Unpacking oracle-java11-set-default-local
> (11.0.12-1~linuxuprising0) over (11.0.12-1~linuxuprising0) ... Setting
> up oracle-java11-set-default-local (11.0.12-1~linuxuprising0) ...
> root@server:~# java --version openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20 OpenJDK
> Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04) OpenJDK
> 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode,
> sharing) root@server:~#  sudo update-alternatives --config java There
> are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
>
> ### Selection    Path
> Priority   Status
>
> - 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode   1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
>   1111      manual mode   2
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
>
> root@server:~# root@server:~# printenv SHELL=/bin/bash
> DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/db
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle

Even more wierdly, there is nothing in the created JAVA_HOME.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install small additional package from the [same PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java) by

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java11-set-default-local
```

to set Oracle Java 11 as default Java version.

Comment: Thanks.  But I did that and nothing.   Below is the output.  Also oddly I just did "sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer-local" and the very same output.  
root@server:~# sudo apt-get install oracle-java11-set-default-local
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java11-set-default-local is already the newest version (11.0.12-1~linuxuprising0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@server:~# java --version

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java11-set-default-local` will help.